# Salesforce Web2Lead - Lead Capture Page: Not available.

Tags: php, salesforce

Upon debug I'm getting a response that states Lead Capture Page: Not available.

Has anyone run into this problem...  I'm passing everything correctly and salesforce.com board is no help at all.

Comment: It's no wonder the forum at Salesfoce is no help. Your question is impossible to answer without seeing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the error message you got is generic, it doesn't say what the error is.

Using the debug=1 param, or the debugemail param, it tries to return to you the page that the post came from.  I think it uses the Referer: header for that.  No referrer header (like if you just curl post data to sf), then you get the line above instead of something like

Lead Capture Page: http://yoursite.com/your/form.php

Here's some other tips, given that sf isn't telling you jack:

- instead of www.salesforce or test.salesforce, try posting to the same subdomain you see when you log in by browser.
- Also look at the return header Is-Processed:, I've seen exceptions in there.
- try the generated form; as generated, you change the subdomain as above and it should work as-is.  then gradually hack your form and the generated form towards each other till they both fail or both succeed.